# ios shows file in mobile safari rather than downloading?

Tags: php, ios, download, mobile-safari

I am using the following code to present a file for download to the user... in this case it is a .csv file.  Works great in all browsers, BUT in IOS it loads the file in the mobile safari browser.  The exact same code works fine for a .zip file (although ios gives the warning it cannot download that type of file).

What gives?  Does ios completely disregard the headers or what?

```
if (is_file($local_path.$file))
{
    //get current ts
    $now = time();

    // set the headers and prevent caching
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Expires: -1');
    header('Cache-Control: public, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$now.'_'.$file.'"');   

    // set the mime type based on extension                 
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Length: '.filesize($local_path.$file).'');

    //download
    readfile($local_path.$file);

    //delete file
    unlink($local_path.$file);
}
```

Comment: I don't know php but I think the problem is not with your code, where do you expect your users to save this file? As far as I know you can't "store" stuff on an ios device as you would on android for example), you'll have to send the .csv file to an app and maybe in your case safari is the only app that can process a .csv.

Comment: Have you tried setting content type to `text/csv` instead of `application/octet-stream`?

Comment: Rearrange your headers so the `Content-*` ones are firsts, and add this one too `header('Content-Description: File Transfer');`

Comment: @LozCherone No, the order of headers doesn't matter if they have different name, check RFC 2616, section 4.2

Comment: I realize ios cannot 'store' files, but it was not the result I expected.  I was expecting something similar to the same script with a .zip file where it shows 'Download Failed - Safari cannot download this file'.  I suppose there are two sides to this... it is nice it opens, but going from my 'site' to basically showing a text file table isn't very aesthetically pleasing plus all navigation, layout, etc of the site is gone.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Mobile Safari - Html download link opens tab instead of downloading file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10490558/mobile-safari-html-download-link-opens-tab-instead-of-downloading-file)